# What's the easiest way to add a contact form for all nodes of a certain content type?

Tags: nodes, forms, emails

I need to add a contact form to all nodes of a certain content type, so when a user submits the form it's delivered to the e-mail address of the author of the node. I tried using Webforms as a block with Contexts but Tokens doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended using Webforms, passing the node author's e-mail using the token [current-page:node:author:mail] for passing the e-mail via a hidden field. I enabled the option to use the webform as a block and Context module for showing that block only in the desired content type.

With the lastest stable versions of Webforms and Token, I had to patch Token module as it's explained in this forum because the token wasn't working with Webforms.

http://doublemthemes.com/comment/3307#comment-3307

Answer (score 0):

There was a module for that, [Author Contact](https://www.drupal.org/project/authorcontact). If you are using Drupal 6, it might still be good. If you are using later version, it's still a decent source of opensource code. There is [Drupal 7 port](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113016), but I can't personally vouch for it. *Seems* good, but I only glanced at code. If it works, it will be *the* easiest way - because that's what it does, nothing less, nothing more.

Alternatively, you could give [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) a try. It does not send email to author out of the box as far as I know, [it was discussed on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1966870), but if you are feeling lucky, it would be worth try again.